# How to retrieve data achieved through PHP and JSON properly (with parse)

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing

everybody!

I'm thinking that I have a problem with json.parse

I submitted a form with ajax to a php page.

```
index.php - full code

        jQuery('#inserir_certificado_usuario').submit(function(){

            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../classes/processa_evento.php",
            data: dados,
            success: function(data)
            {

            var data = data;

            var arr = JSON.parse(data);
                var i;
                var out = "";
                for(i = 0; i < arr.certificado.length; i++) {
                out += "Trabalho: " + 
                    arr.certificado[i].id_trabalho + " - " + arr.certificado[i].titulo_trabalho +
                    "<br />Usuário: " +
                    arr.certificado[i].id_usuario + " - " + arr.certificado[i].nome_autor +
                    "<br />Autenticador Nº: " +
                    arr.certificado[i].autenticador +
                    "<br /><a href='../certificados/ver_certificado.php?caso=0&autenticador="+arr.certificado[i].autenticador+"' target='certificado'>VER CERTIFICADO</a>";
                                                }
                out += "";
                document.getElementById("divCarregaDestinatarios").innerHTML = out;
            },
            error: function()
            {
           //do nothing
              }
            });
            return false;
            });

    <div id='divCarregaDestinatarios'></div>
```

The data is received like this.

```
processa_evento.php

    $autenticador = $_POST[autenticador];
    $id_certificado_base = $_POST[id_certificado_base];
    $id_evento_certificado = $_POST[id_evento_certificado];
    $id_trabalho = $_POST[id_trabalho];
    $titulo_trabalho = $_POST[titulo_trabalho];
    $id_usuario = $_POST[id_usuario];
    $nome_autor = $_POST[nome_autor];
    $timestamp_certificado = $_POST[timestamp_certificado];
    $token_trabalho = $_POST[token_trabalho];

//create code for json
    $json_resposta['certificado'] = array('id_trabalho'=>"$id_trabalho", 'titulo_trabalho'=>"$titulo_trabalho", 'id_usuario'=>"$id_usuario", 'nome_autor'=>"$nome_autor", 'autenticador'=>"$autenticador");

    $json_resposta = json_encode($json_resposta, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    //replace \\n which would cause errors in JavaScript
    $json_resposta = str_replace("\\n", " ", $json_resposta);

    echo "$json_resposta";
    //echo something like this
      //{"certificado":[{"id_trabalho":"13","titulo_trabalho":"O PROBLEMA DA DEGRADAÇÃO AMBIENTAL E GESTÃO NO MUNICÍPIO DE GUARAMIRANGA - CEARÁ: UM OLHAR SOBRE A LEI 110\/2005","id_usuario":"8","nome_autor":"Ariana  Rodrigues Bezerra ","autenticador":"OHIC.SRZL.NZAT.W2PQ.A5X0.KYKD"}]}
```

So, returning to the index.php I'm retrieving some data from this php page (processa_evento.php) through ajax using the "success method":

```
index.php
    ...
    success: function(data)
            {

            var data = data;
    ...
```

After tha I retrieved the data, I would like to create some html elements with javascript and the data using this code:

```
index.php
    ...
    var arr = JSON.parse(data);
                var i;
                var out = "";
                for(i = 0; i < arr.certificado.length; i++) {
                out += "Trabalho: " + 
                    arr.certificado[i].id_trabalho + " - " + arr.certificado[i].titulo_trabalho +
                    "<br />Usuário: " +
                    arr.certificado[i].id_usuario + " - " + arr.certificado[i].nome_autor +
                    "<br />Autenticador Nº: " +
                    arr.certificado[i].autenticador +
                    "<br /><a href='../certificados/ver_certificado.php?caso=0&autenticador="+arr.certificado[i].autenticador+"' target='certificado'>VER CERTIFICADO</a>";
                                                }
                out += "";
                document.getElementById("divCarregaDestinatarios").innerHTML = out;
```

But some how I'm getting this error (mozilla firebug) at index.php:

**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**
**console.log(JSON.parse(data))**

What is happening? I'm new at this. Could someone help me, please?
Best regards, folks!

Comment: Why are you calling `JSON.parse()` yourself? jQuery will parse the response for you automatically and pass the resulting object to your success handler - assuming the response has the right `Content-Type` set (if not, add the `dataType:'json'` option to your ajax call). Also, why `var data = data;`? You don't need that.

Comment: Hi, @nnnnnn! If I not parse it, this error occurs: **TypeError: arr.certificado is undefined**

Comment: Please add `console.log(data)` as the first line of your success function and let us know what it shows.

Comment: @nnnnnn, I'm getting this: "{"certificado":[{"id_trabalho":"13","titulo_trabalho":"O PROBLEMA DA DEGRADAÇÃO AMBIENTAL E GESTÃO NO MUNICÍPIO DE GUARAMIRANGA - CEARÁ: UM OLHAR SOBRE A LEI 110\/2005","id_usuario":"8","nome_autor":"Ariana  Rodrigues Bezerra ","autenticador":"SXB8.G4FI.CRVV.EXJP.YLIY.ZB32"}]}"

Comment: @nnnnnn, when I use dataType:"json" - I get error from the ajax.submit

Comment: @nnnnnn, if I paste the text above, in var data (eg: var data = '{"certificado":[{"id_usuario":"8","nome_autor":"Ariana Rodrigues Bezerra "}]}') It works.